# How to represent Get error type using a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, custom-errors

How to represent the following using a switch statement?

```
if (e instanceof EvalError) {
    console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
  } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
    console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is using strict comparison, you could take `true` as expression and the other test as value for testing.

```
switch (true) {
    case e instanceof EvalError:
        console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
        break;
    case e instanceof RangeError:
        console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nina... dont know why I couldn't figure that one out ... brain not functioning